# How should I troubleshoot a Qnx ntp synchronisation issue?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntp

I setup the w32time service to act as an ntp server, and it has been confirmed on at least one other client (MacOS X). I've used a few different utilities in Windows that indicate that there indeed is an ntp service responding.

Here's a snippet from ntpd (on Qnx run as ntpd -ddqn -c ntp.conf):

```
poll_update: at 1998 192.168.2.10 flags 0081 poll 6 burst 0 last 1998 next 2064
    MCAST   *****sendpkt(fd=6 dst=192.168.2.10, src=192.168.2.220, ttl=0, len=48)
transmit: at 1998 192.168.2.220->192.168.2.10 modeinput_handler: if=2 fd=6 length 48 from c0a8020a 192.168.2.10 3
receive: at 1998 192.168.2.220<-192.168.2.10 restrict 00
receive: at 1998 192.168.2.220<-192.168.2.10 mode 4 code 1
poll_update: at 1998 192.168.2.10 flags 0081 poll 6 burst 0 last 1998 next 2062
clock_filter: n 2 off 318.028919 del 0.001000 dsp 0.016994 jit 0.094653, age 0
```

I am not adept at deciphering this. I'm hoping someone can educate, or simply tell me what's wrong. There has to be a reason why the Qnx implementation isn't synchronising. I think I can pick out the bit about the offset (being ahead 318s) -- which would be correct.

Just why isn't it fixing the local clock?

Answer (score 0):

How long did you wait for the synchronization to happen? It can take up to 10 minutes in some cases. Can you get the time using:

```
# ntpdate <time server ip address>
```

For what's it's worth, the QNX version of ntp's utilities are marginally different than what's available in linux and mac, it's basically the same tools just built with a different compiler.